# Why is a decreasing for loop working in this problem and a growing one isn't?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a leetCode exercise and I have no idea why a decreasing for loop is working but the same exact code with an increasing one is not. Can someone explain why?. This is the problem:

Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that value in-place and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.

//not working

```
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for(let i = nums.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(val == nums[i]) {
         nums.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
  return nums.length;
};
```

//working

```
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (nums[i] == val){
            nums.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
};
```

Comment: there is no difference in your examples, it seems like incrementation should be in the first one.

Comment: @KirillLiubun yes, the OP appears to have the wrong code sample for their "not working" version.

Comment: You have an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You remove `1` (`i = 0`). Your array now is `[2, 3, 4]` but your `i` is at `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem with mutating an array "in place", and working backwards is the standard workaround.

Whenever you remove the current element you modify the indices of any element from that point forwards.

In particular, if you're working forwards then when removing element `i` you then need to *reconsider that element in the next pass*, because what was element `i + 1` before the splice is now element `i`, so you have to skip the increment:

```
const removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ) {
        if (val === nums[i]) {
            nums.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
};
```

Working backwards avoids the problem, because you've already seen those (now renumbered) elements.

Comment: Right, it makes sense. Thank you so much!